# select all rows with the maximum number from repeated sequence in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a very big dataframe with repeated measures but no column is available to group. The key to select needed rows is to geet the max(id) taking into account the repeated sequence is from 0 to 7 this way:

```
temperature   weekday   id
32            monday    0
34            thursday  0
34            saturday  1
55            wednesday 2
43            friday    0
45            sunday    1
42            friday    0
```

desired output (max id from sequence):

```
temperature   weekday   id
32            monday    0
55            wednesday 2
45            sunday    1
42            friday    0
```

Comment: Friday has two id's equal to 0.  in that case, which value of temperature should be selected?  Also, I think we need more data from you.  Use `dput(yourdataframe)` to provide more data.

Comment: there is no grouping column. weekday doesn't matter. The need is to select the max(id) for every sequence. If t here is two 0 in a row the first 0 is selected, and the second 0 depending on the next number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to select every row where the next `id` isn't higher than the current `id`. With `dplyr`:

```
your_data %>% filter(lead(id, default = 0) <= id)
```

(The default makes sure the last row of the data is included.)

Comment: i am astonished this way of thinking is the key to the solution. Yes, "the next id that isn't higher than the current". I am embarrassed this idea did not came to me....a bit of explanation on your solution please? I do not fully understand the code

Comment: I started to go down a more complicated route of identifying sequences, but then when I realized you only wanted the last one, this solution became clear to me ;)

Comment: I'm not sure what needs explaining. `lead(id)` is the next ID, `id` is the current ID, so `lead(id) <= id` is exactly *"the next id that isn't higher than the current"*. For the last row, there is no next ID, so we set `default = 0` to be used in the last row so that it is kept.